# I am using curl to download profile photo. Is that right method?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
function getFacebookPhoto($img,$fullpath) {

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $img);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
$user_curl_image = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if(file_exists($fullpath)){
    @unlink($fullpath);
}
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $user_curl_image);
fclose($fp); 
}
```

This is the script i use to download photos. 
Is it rightway to do it?

I use this function inside facebook apps.

Comment: why dont you just link to them <img src="http:////www.facebook.com/image.png" />

Comment: i need to download the photos to server to process them

Comment: then yes, you doing it correctly, BUT be careful using script that create files on your server. I suggest you store them outside the document root.

Comment: Why? Is there any problem on this? I use imagecreatefromjpeg or gif, png methods.